# Парсер яндекс почты.все время перебрасывает на облегчоную версию сайта.как попасть на полную версию?

Tags: php, php-curl

```
$common_yandex = curl_init('https://passport.yandex.ru/auth?from=mail&origin=hostroot_homer_auth_ru&retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yandex.ru');
//https://passport.yandex.ua/auth?origin=home_desktop_ua&retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yandex.ua%2F&backpath=https%3A%2F%2Fyandex.ua
//curl_setopt($common_yandex,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36');  //показываем сайту с какого браузера зашли
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login=$login&passwd=$password");
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_box);
//curl_setopt($common_yandex,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$html = curl_exec($common_yandex);
```

Comment: А что вы такое пытаетесь сделать и не проще ли взять imap?

Comment: необходимо парсить почту по ключевому слову и определенный промежуток временни

Comment: Чем imap не подошёл для этой задачи?

Comment: не хватка знаний видать) могли бы дать ссылку на ресурс который мне помог в этом разобратья ?